# Angular errors when importing MatProgressSpinnerModule

Tags: angular

So, I'm looking to add a loading spinner to my angular app. I'm getting the following errors on the angular cli when importing MatProgressSpinnerModule in
`app.module.ts`:

```
`./node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/esm2015/bidi.js:76:78-86 - Error: export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'DOCUMENT') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser' (possible exports: BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule, By, DomSanitizer, EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS, EventManager, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HAMMER_LOADER, HammerGestureConfig, HammerModule, Meta, Title, TransferState, VERSION, disableDebugTools, enableDebugTools, makeStateKey, platformBrowser, ɵBROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS, ɵBROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵBrowserDomAdapter, ɵBrowserGetTestability, ɵDomEventsPlugin, ɵDomRendererFactory2, ɵDomSanitizerImpl, ɵDomSharedStylesHost, ɵELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS, ɵELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵHAMMER_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵHammerGesturesPlugin, ɵINTERNAL_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, ɵKeyEventsPlugin, ɵNAMESPACE_URIS, ɵSharedStylesHost, ɵTRANSITION_ID, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_a, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_b, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_c, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_d, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_e, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_f, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_g, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_h, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_i, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_j, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_k, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_l, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_m, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_n, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_o, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_p, ɵescapeHtml, ɵflattenStyles, ɵgetDOM, ɵinitDomAdapter, ɵshimContentAttribute, ɵshimHostAttribute)

./node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/esm2015/bidi.js:3m164:46-54 - Error: export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'DOCUMENT') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser' (possible exports: BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule, By, DomSanitizer, EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS, EventManager, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HAMMER_LOADER, HammerGestureConfig, HammerModule, Meta, Title, TransferState, VERSION, disableDebugTools, enableDebugTools, makeStateKey, platformBrowser, ɵBROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS, ɵBROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵBrowserDomAdapter, ɵBrowserGetTestability, ɵDomEventsPlugin, ɵDomRendererFactory2, ɵDomSanitizerImpl, ɵDomSharedStylesHost, ɵELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS, ɵELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵHAMMER_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵHammerGesturesPlugin, ɵINTERNAL_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, ɵKeyEventsPlugin, ɵNAMESPACE_URIS, ɵSharedStylesHost, ɵTRANSITION_ID, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_a, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_b, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_c, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_d, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_e, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_f, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_g, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_h, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_i, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_j, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_k, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_l, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_m, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_n, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_o, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_p, ɵescapeHtml, ɵflattenStyles, ɵgetDOM, ɵinitDomAdapter, ɵshimContentAttribute, ɵshimHostAttribute)

./node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/esm2015/bidi.js:177:58-66 - Error: export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'DOCUMENT') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser' (possible exports: BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule, By, DomSanitizer, EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS, EventManager, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HAMMER_LOADER, HammerGestureConfig, HammerModule, Meta, Title, TransferState, VERSION, disableDebugTools, enableDebugTools, makeStateKey, platformBrowser, ɵBROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS, ɵBROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵBrowserDomAdapter, ɵBrowserGetTestability, ɵDomEventsPlugin, ɵDomRendererFactory2, ɵDomSanitizerImpl, ɵDomSharedStylesHost, ɵELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS, ɵELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵHAMMER_PROVIDERS__POST_R3__, ɵHammerGesturesPlugin, ɵINTERNAL_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, ɵKeyEventsPlugin, ɵNAMESPACE_URIS, ɵSharedStylesHost, ɵTRANSITION_ID, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_a, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_b, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_c, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_d, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_e, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_f, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_g, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_h, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_i, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_j, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_k, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_l, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_m, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_n, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_o, ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_platform_browser_p, ɵescapeHtml, ɵflattenStyles, ɵgetDOM, ɵinitDomAdapter, ɵshimContentAttribute, ɵshimHostAttribute)

./node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js:6:9-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/Subject' in 'C:\Users\R881312\Documents\TimeoutProject\TimeoutProject\PerformanceTraceAPI\ClientApp\node_modules\rxjs'

Error: node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/datetime/date-adapter.d.ts:9:10 - error TS2305: Module '"rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.

9 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
           ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/datetime/date-adapter.d.ts:10:10 - error TS2305: Module '"rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.

10 import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
            ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Observable';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subject' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Subject';
```

I have no clue why this is happening, did I forget some imports?. I'm using angular v12. This happens right after I try to import the MatProgressSpinnerModule, everything compiles fine before this

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.2",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.2",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.14.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jw-angular-pagination": "^1.2.0",
    "msal": "^1.4.11",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you attach the **package.json** to the question? Suspect that it is due to a version compatibility issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have attached package.json

Comment: after adding `MatProgressSpinnerModule`, did stop the server and runs again? if yes, delete node_module and run in your terminal `npm i`.

Comment: @Hamada just tried that to no avail